# Indexing using variadic templates

Tags: templates, c++11, variadic

Let's say that I have a parameter pack I'm unrolling, e.g.

```
template<typename... P> void f(P...&& args) {
    some_other_func(std::forward<P>(args)...);
}
```

Now let's say that I have some other minor function that these objects need to go through.

```
template<typename T> T&& some_func(T&& ref) {
    // replace with actual logic
    return std::forward<T>(ref);
}
```

I would normally just replace with

```
template<typename... P> void f(P...&& args) {
    some_other_func(some_func(args)...);
}
```

But what do I do if `some_func` requires more information about the parameter than just it's type, like for example, it's position numerically in the parameter pack? So that instead of expanding to

```
some_other_func(some_func(arg1), some_func(arg2));
```

I could mke it expand to

```
some_other_func(some_func(arg1, 1), some_func(arg2, 2));
```

for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I've solved this before but can't recall how. Oh well, here's a fresh look.

The sequence of numbers can be translated into the argument sequence using `std::get`, so it is more fundamental. So, assuming that I need to implement some kind of custom tool, a number pack generator seems like a good choice.

(Gah, this was incredibly tedious. I did peek at Howard's answer and learned about `forward_as_tuple`, but that function doesn't even exist yet on my compiler or ideone.com, so blah. There are a lot of things I still need to get straight, and this is certainly one of the worst functional languages ever invented.)

http://ideone.com/u5noV

```
#include <tuple>

// Generic pack array (metacontainer)
template< typename T, T ... seq > struct value_sequence {
    // Append a value to the array (metafunction)
    template< T val > struct append
        { typedef value_sequence< T, seq..., val > type; };
};

// Generate a sequential array (metafunction)
template< size_t N >
struct index_sequence {
    typedef typename index_sequence< N - 1 >::type
                      ::template append< N - 1 >::type type;
};

template<>
struct index_sequence< 0 >
    { typedef value_sequence< size_t > type; };

// Generate indexes up to size of given tuple (metafunction)
template< typename T >
struct index_tuple {
    typedef typename index_sequence< std::tuple_size< T >::value
                                   >::type type;
};

// The magic function: passes indexes, makes all the function calls
template< typename F, typename G,
          typename T, size_t ... N >
void compose_with_indexes_helper( F f, G g, T args,
        value_sequence< size_t, N ... > ) {
    f( g( std::get< N >( args ), N ) ... );
}

template< typename F, typename G, typename ... T >
void compose_with_indexes( F f, G g, T && ... args ) {
    typedef std::tuple< T && ... > tuple_t;
    compose_with_indexes_helper
//        forwarding seems broken on ideone.com/GCC 4.5.1, work around.
//        ( f, g, std::forward_as_tuple( std::forward( args ) ... ) );
        ( f, g, tuple_t( args ... ), typename index_tuple< tuple_t >::type() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this one. Certainly not going to use libstdc++ private internals.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that is more tedious than C++ with tuple and variadic templates is C++ without tuple and variadic templates. ;-)  I strongly suspect that over time we (the C++ community) will defacto-standardize on helpful utilities similar to those you show above, or to what I took advantage of in libc++.  And then hopefully things won't be so tedious.

Comment: @Howard: `tuple` I like, it's the parameter pack interface that seems to resist encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

It is a little convoluted.  But here is a working prototype of your code using several private utilities of [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/), found in
[<__tuple>](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/__tuple), and [<tuple>](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/tuple).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
int
some_func(T&& ref, size_t I)
{
    std::cout << "ref = " << ref << ", I = " << I << '\n';
    return 0;
}

template<typename... T, size_t ...Indx>
void
some_other_func(std::tuple<T...> ref, std::__tuple_indices<Indx...>) {
    // replace with actual logic
    std::__swallow(some_func(std::get<Indx>(ref), Indx)...);
}


template<typename... P>
void
f(P&&... args)
{
    some_other_func(std::forward_as_tuple<P...>(std::forward<P>(args)...),
                    typename std::__make_tuple_indices<sizeof...(P)>::type());
}

int main()
{
    f("zero", "one", "two", "three");
}

ref = zero, I = 0
ref = one, I = 1
ref = two, I = 2
ref = three, I = 3
```

Comment: Big laugh, not even going to try! :-)